# HTML form checkbox textarea input

Tags: html

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubojD.png

Basically, the field has a textarea enabled by a checkbox state. If the checkbox is not checked then it won't send the text in the textarea to the server when submitted otherwise it will. I can't seem to find a solution to getting this working. I would prefer not requiring js.

Below is what I have at the moment.

```html
<form method="post" action="" id="submitform">

<fieldset>
  <legend></legend>
  <input type="checkbox" id="urban" name="pref" value="urban"><label for="urban">Urban (cities)</label>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="rural" name="pref" value="rural"><label for="rural">Rural</label>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mountains" name="pref" value="mountains"><label for="mountains">Mountains</label>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="other" name="pref"><label for="other">Other</label><textarea rows="1" cols="20" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like HTML 5 doesn't provide a way to do that. With JavaScript, you can simply attach a event listener to the element.

```js
const $otherCheck = document.querySelector("#other");
const $otherTextarea = document.querySelector("textarea");

function disabler() {
  if (!$otherCheck.checked) {
    $otherTextarea.value = "";
    $otherTextarea.disabled = true;
  } else {
    $otherTextarea.disabled = false;
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", disabler)
$otherCheck.addEventListener("click", disabler);
```

```html
<form method="post" action="" id="submitform">
  <fieldset>
    <legend></legend>
    
    <input type="checkbox" id="urban" name="pref" value="urban">
    <label for="urban">Urban (cities)</label>
    <br>
    
    <input type="checkbox" id="rural" name="pref" value="rural">
    <label for="rural">Rural</label>
    <br>
    
    <input type="checkbox" id="mountains" name="pref" value="mountains">
    <label for="mountains">Mountains</label>
    <br>
    
    <input type="checkbox" id="other" name="pref">
    <label for="other">Other</label>
    <textarea rows="1" cols="20" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```